# Div is not changing width after other class activation and width change - sidebar and fluid page content

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidebar

I made sidebar menu with YT (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEfaoAa99XY) tutorial but there is one thing that didn't work.

When I collaps sidebar menu, the content box with text should expand and fill the gap after sidebar but it is not happening.

It should be done by this code:

```
.sidebar.active ~ .content-box {
width: calc(100% - 80px);
left: 80px;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

}

I checked and .sidebar is set to active after click on button. And when I delete ".sidebar.active ~ " the content box width is changing so I don't think that there is any colliding code.

Can anyone help me found what is wrong with this code?

Here is live page: https://gearlistmaker.com/

And here is github repository: https://github.com/jankamon/GearListMaker

Comment: Your problem exists in your DOM Flow, your main content area shouldn't be absolute positioned and you don't need the calc widths and most of the other stuff. If you provide a simple reproducible example of your current issue here on SO so we don't have to go copy/paste everything then myself or someone else can easily show you how to remedy it and improve your semantic structure overall. PS - I'm a big hiker/camper so happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what do you mean by "If you provide a simple reproducible example of your current issue here on SO"? How can I do that, on live version there is visible problem.

I think I'll try to rebuild structure by myself, not using tutorials.